# How to optimally use sub-sections of a buffer with VAO?

Tags: opengl, vbo, keyframe, vao

I have loaded many frames into large VBOs (all belonging to the same VAO).
As (short) example I have:

```
GLfloat myBuf[] = {0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.9} // one point for each frames
```

Then I build my VAO as:

```
GLuint vao =0;
glGenVertexArrays(1, &vao);
glBindVertexArray(vao);
GLuint vbo = 0;
glGenBuffers(1, &vbo);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(GLfloat)*3*2, myBuf, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, 0);
...
```

Then, in order to render a sub-section I do:

```
glBindVertexArray(vao);
// enable vertexes
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, vbo);
// frame is 0 or 1
glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 0, reinterpret_cast<void*>(sizeof(float)*3*frame));
// draw 1 point using offset of index array
glDrawElements(GL_POINTS, 1, GL_UNSIGNED_SHORT, 0);
```

Is the above the only way of achieving to render a sub-section dynamically? In my original code after I initialized the VAO, I deleted the VBO and all is fine - with this code of course I have to keep the VBO.

Am I right the only way to achieve this is to use `glVertexAttribPointer` the way above?
Is there a better way of doing it?

Comment: "*In my original code after I initialized the VAO, I deleted the VBO and all is fine*" Then you got "lucky".

Comment: @NicolBolas I thought at first too (i did _not_ delete them originally), but actually is part of the specs (I've read it on stackoverflow), handles must then be managed inside the VAO. I was suggested to do so...

Comment: "*I was suggested to do so...*" Then I would suggest that you not listen to the advice of anyone who suggests that it's a good thing to delete an object that you are still using.

Comment: @NicolBolas I read somewhere that when the VAO is finalized, all the VBOs are bound to it hence one can 'dereference' them. I'll find he link and confirm. Anyway, what about my question?